# Chrome's Frame Rate meter, how to interpret?

Tags: google-chrome

I am playing with Chrome's FPS meter, but have some difficulty understanding it.

My understanding is Chrome targets 60 FPS, and the higher, the smoother.
However, I see the frame rate drop to 1 fps on some sites, but I do not feel it's sluggish.

For example,here's screen shot on google's own search page.
the frame rate is 4.7 fps,
and then when I start scrolling the page, the rate seems goes up to 30 or even sometimes 59.
The page is very responsive in the whole process.

So how to use this frame rate? Seems useless for monitoring page smoothness.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Google Search page is (while you are not scrolling) static. The only dynamics are hover links but it features no animations for example react components. Therefore Chrome does not have to render the page at 60 fps to save power.

Try it for yourself if you visit a site with animated objects [like this site](https://catalinmiron.github.io/react-typical/)
You can see that chrome really only renders new frames when its forced. So if your animation requires constant 60 fps chrome would render them, but if its an animation with pauses (like in the example page) chrome tries to minimize the used power.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My question is that this is not going to helpful if I want to tell my animation is smooth?  Say it renders in 30 fps, how would I tell if it only needs 30 fps, or it's too sluggish that it only can be rendered at 30 fps?